# Touchpad doesn't react to tap

Tags: debian, xfce

I have Debian Stretch (xfce) and my touchpad doesn't react to tap.

I searched some solutions to fix it, example:

- create ***50-synaptics.conf*** to **/etc/X11/Xsession.d/** and **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/**

***50-synaptics.conf***

```
Section “InputClass”
        Identifier  “touchpad catchall”
        Driver  “synaptics”
        MatchIsTouchpad “on”
MatchDevicePath “/dev/input/event*”
        Option  “TapButton1”  “1”
        Option  “TapButton2”  “2”
        Option  “TapButton3”  “3”
```

But If I try something solution, I every get crash with starting Light-Display-Manager.

I have to delete ***50-synaptics.conf*** and reboot notebook.

So can I fix my problem with touchpad?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to [just `synaptics.conf`](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Desktop_configuration)? Also, are you able to try configuration through `synclient`? It should be installed alongside `synaptics`.

Answer (score -1):

Debian 9 "Stretch" is using **libinput** driver

```
$ mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
$ echo 'Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
$ systemctl restart lightdm
```

From [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Enable_tapping_on_touchpad)